# Rails 5 API - parent 'must exist' error when trying to create a child record via POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I'm building my first API (ever) in Rails 5 as a learning experience.

I'm using Rails in --api mode and have the active_model_serializers gem installed.

The API is based on a relationship between ships and voyages.

A ship has_many :voyages and a voyage belongs_to :ship.

Using Postman to check the voyages API endpoint I'm getting this as the return value:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "tstd_id": 94583,
  "year": 1722,
  "began": null,
  "trade_began": null,
  "departed_africa": null,
  "arrived_slaves": null,
  "ended": null,
  "length": null,
  "middle_passage_length": null,
  "port_departed": "Liverpool",
  "ship": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary",
    "flag": "British",
    "rig": null,
    "tonnage": null,
    "standardized_tonnage": null,
    "year_constructed": null,
    "place_registered": null,
    "year_registered": null,
    "from": null,
    "to": null
  }
}
```

When I try to create a new voyage via POST using Key: voyage[ship][id] Value: 1 I'm getting a return from the API of 'must exist'

The error I'm getting from the Rails console is:

```
Started POST "/voyages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-28 11:03:47 +0100
Processing by VoyagesController#create as */*
Parameters: {"voyage"=>{"ship"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "year"=>"4"}}
Unpermitted parameter: ship
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveModel::Errors (0.14ms)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 9ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have ship's `id` with you, then you have to send it as `ship_id` instead of `ship[id]`. Your parameters should look like,

```
{ "voyage"=> { "ship_id" => "1", "year" => "4" } }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the exact same error when passing ship_id instead of ship[id] via POST. The parameters are returning as you suggest they should but I'm getting an unpermitted parameter ship_id in the console.

Comment: Which is because I didn't have ship_id in my list of permitted parameters in the controller - oops! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this issue when creating the new object without qualifying by the parents, such as:

```
@obj = SomeObjectType.where(:some_parent_id => params[:some_parent_id]).first_or_create
@obj.save!
```

This will error in the same way, if SomeObjectType has more than the one parent, for instance a user, which typically is created in the following way in most examples:

```
@obj = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).objs.new(obj_params)
@obj.save!
```

in the first case that is erroring, you have to assign the user (or whatever parent is erroring) through the belongs_to relationship:

```
 @obj = SomeObjectType.where(:some_parent_id => params[:some_parent_id]).first_or_create
 @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]);
 @obj.user = @user
 @obj.save!
```

There might be a more concise way to associate these parents, but this solves the listed issue.